# How does gradle actually work in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

OK, the above question does feel generic and broad but i have this confusion which i need to clear.

I was building a project in android with few custom xml animation, one of them was parallax scroll view which i got from https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll and he told to import the line `compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'` which i did and o separately downloaded its classes, then to use parallax view i had to define my view as

```
<com.example.hasan.jsoncountries.ParallaxScrollView
....
...
</com.example.hasan.jsoncountries.ParallaxScrollView>
```

which let me use the parallax class.

Now if i try to comment out the ParallaxScrollView class i some times get error or sometimes it works.

Now my question is do we need to separately download the java class files after importing the gradle command ?

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hasan.jsoncountries"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'

}
```

after I comment my ParallaxScrollView.Java

I get this in logcat.

```
06-17 19:06:39.084  25611-25611/com.example.hasan.jsoncountries E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hasan.jsoncountries, PID: 25611
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hasan.jsoncountries/com.example.hasan.jsoncountries.SingleItemView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.example.hasan.jsoncountries.ParallaxScrollView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.example.hasan.jsoncountries.ParallaxScrollView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.hasan.jsoncountries.SingleItemView.onCreate(SingleItemView.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.hasan.jsoncountries.ParallaxScrollView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hasan.jsoncountries-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.hasan.jsoncountries.SingleItemView.onCreate(SingleItemView.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.hasan.jsoncountries.ParallaxScrollView
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 22 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is do we need to separately download the java class
>   files after importing the gradle command ?

Absolutely **no**. One of the great things about gradle it's the use of Maven.

Maven is a central repository system (there's the MavenCentral, but also others), so the moment you put the complete specification of the library you need (in your case `compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'`), gradle will download that library on that specific version from the central repository.

If the library you want is in a different repository, usually you will find on their git page telling you which other `buildscript->respository` to add to your gradle file.

That means, all you must do is to add the `compile` line and click the icon to update your gradle build script in Android Studio, this will trigger the process of reading the `build.gradle` file and download any necessary libraries. Those are downloaded in the gradle cache directory.

So my suggestion is to: delete, remove any downloaded classes you put on your project and let gradle do its beauty.

Comment: Sure, if you have this great tool, why reinventing the wheel ??

Comment: i tried to run the project with out the class files i.e. i commented the class, and it crashed my app, if i dont comment the class, the app runs fine

Comment: @penta so you should ask a different question. Post your `build.gradle` and the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: @Budius i have added gradle and logcat

Comment: because `com.example` is not part of the library, the library is `com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView`